# retrieve data and update the data from an XML file using c#

Tags: c#, html, xml, xpath

I have been set a task to retrieve data and update the data from an XML file.

My code is working correctly, but I need to get rid of the `"` sign when writing to the XML file. How can I do this?

XML:

```xml
<td width="40%" align="center" valign="middle">
 <img Name='logo'/>
</td>
```

My C# code:

```cs
string xDoc = @"Resources\general.Xslt";
XmlDocument xDocument = new XmlDocument();
xDocument.Load(xDoc);
XmlNode sorgu = xDocument.SelectSingleNode("//@Name");
sorgu.InnerText = "'logo' style='width: 250px' align='middle' alt='E-Fatura Logo' src='data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64Text + "'";
xDocument.Save(xDoc);
```

After running the program, this is the XML:

```xml
<td width="40%" align="center" valign="middle">
<img Name="'logo' style='width: 250px' align='middle' alt='E-Fatura Logo' src='data:image/jpeg;base64,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'" />
</td>
****here after the name and at the end " there should be no quotes****
```

Comment: Are you looking to remove the last double quote? So `//Z'"` ← the last character here?

Comment: yes and the top one `Name=" ' ` here 
I want to delete after equal

Comment: Quite unclear what you have trouble with - you seem to know how to set attributes (in a roundabout way, but...) and it sounds like you want to set multiple attributes for the node... So why don't you do just that? Or maybe I misunderstood the goal...

Comment: There is an accounting program for it, I am doing the logo insertion part and the logo image must be in base64 code for the government to accept this invoice, so I have to do it like this. Without these double quotes, the code I wrote works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following :

```
       const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement img = doc.Descendants("img").First();
            string style = "width: 250px";
            string align = "middle";
            string alt = "E-Fatura Logo";
            string src = "data:image/jpeg";
            string base64Text = "the text here";
            img.Add(new object[] {
                new XAttribute("style", style),
                new XAttribute("align", align),
                new XAttribute("alt", alt),
                new XAttribute("src", src),
                base64Text
            });
        }
```

Comment: thank you this works but the application doesn't refresh while running I have to close and open it how do I refresh it so I can see the img

Comment: Where is code to display?  Often issues like this are due to control not getting repainted.  Often solution is simple.  Just set control to null and then back to image.

Comment: I don't understand how, can you give an example?

Comment: For example if you had a DGV.  Normally you have dg1.DataSource = dt;  So get it to repaint you would do dg1.DataSource = null; and then dg1.DataSource = dt;